# Game Of Strings

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, game-theory

There are two strings A and B. Initially, some strings A’ and B’ are written on the sheet of paper. A’ is always a substring of A and B’ is always a substring of B. A move consists of appending a letter to exactly one of these strings: either to A’ or to B’. After the move the constraint of A’ being a substring of A and B’ is a substring of B should still be satisfied. Players take their moves alternately. We call a pair (A’, B’) a position.

Two players are playing this game optimally. That means that if a player has a move that leads to his/her victory, he/she will definitely use this move. If a player is unable to make a move, he loses.

Alice and Bob are playing this game. Alice makes the first move. As always, she wants to win and this time she does a clever trick. She wants the starting position to be the Kth lexicographically winning position for the first player (i.e. her). Consider two positions (A’1, B’1) and (A’2, B’2). We consider the first position lexicographically smaller than the second if A1 is lexicographically smaller than A2, or if A1 is equal to A2 and B1 is lexicographically smaller than B2.

What will be such a position, knowing the strings A, B and the integer K.

Note : Some of these strings can be empty. If there’s no such pair, we need to tell that their is  “no solution” .

EXAMPLE : Length of A=2 , Length of B=2 and say K=5 .The strings be

```
ab
cd
```

Here answer will be :

```
a
cd
```

Comment: I don't see the point of this game. As you can always append a letter to a (proper) substring to get another substring, and you append 1 letter each move, the winning player only depends of the number (odd or even) of letters to append. Or does append means "at the end" only ?

Comment: @Xoff append means at end only

Comment: This sounds like the game [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) with two heaps, think of the stones lying in a row "covering" the letters of $A$ and $B$, and appending a substring would correspond to removing the stones covering said substring.

Comment: @Arthur, except you can do nasty things with some words like "coconuts". I like this game :)

Comment: @Xoff Haha..I too like it..:)

Comment: @Arthur Could you please explain your approach in detail?

Comment: @Arthur Nim values will growth with repetition, as you can have some choice of your move. This makes winning positions more complex to compute. Coconuts is not really useful, as the choice does not change anything, but Barbarian is more fun. And the empty substring from Barbarian has nim value $*3$.

Comment: Write down $A$ and $B$. Cover the letters with one stone each, and let each of the covered words be a nim-pile. If you in your game would append a substring, you would in nim remove the stones covering said substring. It's not an exact equivalence, since as mentioned a substring can appear multiple times. As mentioned with coconuts, if $A'$ is "co", I can on my turn decide whether I want there to be $4$ or $6$ stones left in the heap, but if I append to $B'$ instead, that choice goes to my opponent. I realize now it's not the same game, but the differences are subtle.

Answer (score 0):

Your game is fun, and it's [a nim game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim), so you can compute [the nim value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbers) of each substring using [the mex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_%28mathematics%29). But to compute the $k$th winning position in lexicographic order is no more simple than computing all winning positions and sorting them in lexicographic order. So you can do a small program that does all the needed computations.

For example for the words "barbarian" and "baggage" you will obtain :

```
   1 : ""          ""      
   2 : ""          "a"     
   3 : ""          "ag"    
   4 : ""          "age"   
   5 : ""          "agg"   
   6 : ""          "agga"  
   7 : ""          "aggag" 
   8 : ""          "aggage"
   9 : ""          "b"     
  10 : ""          "ba"    
  11 : ""          "bag"   
  12 : ""          "bagg"  
  13 : ""          "bagga" 
  14 : ""          "baggag"
  15 : ""          "baggage"
  16 : ""          "e"     
  17 : ""          "g"     
  18 : ""          "ga"    
  19 : ""          "gag"   
  20 : ""          "gage"  
  21 : ""          "ge"    
  22 : ""          "gg"    
  23 : ""          "gga"   
  24 : ""          "ggag"  
  25 : ""          "ggage" 
  26 : "a"         "a"     
  27 : "a"         "ag"    
  28 : "a"         "age"   
  29 : "a"         "agga"  
  30 : "a"         "aggage"
  31 : "a"         "b"     
  32 : "a"         "bag"   
  33 : "a"         "bagga" 
  34 : "a"         "baggage"
  35 : "a"         "e"     
  36 : "a"         "g"     
  37 : "a"         "ga"    
  38 : "a"         "gage"  
  39 : "a"         "ge"    
  40 : "a"         "gga"   
  41 : "a"         "ggage" 
  42 : "an"        ""      
  43 : "an"        "ag"    
  44 : "an"        "agg"   
  45 : "an"        "aggag" 
  46 : "an"        "ba"    
  47 : "an"        "bagg"  
  48 : "an"        "baggag"
  49 : "an"        "g"     
  50 : "an"        "gag"   
  51 : "an"        "gg"    
  52 : "an"        "ggag"  
  53 : "ar"        ""      
  54 : "ar"        "a"     
  55 : "ar"        "age"   
  56 : "ar"        "agg"   
  57 : "ar"        "agga"  
  58 : "ar"        "aggag" 
  59 : "ar"        "aggage"
  60 : "ar"        "b"     
  61 : "ar"        "ba"    
  62 : "ar"        "bag"   
  63 : "ar"        "bagg"  
  64 : "ar"        "bagga" 
  65 : "ar"        "baggag"
  66 : "ar"        "baggage"
  67 : "ar"        "e"     
  68 : "ar"        "ga"    
  69 : "ar"        "gag"   
  70 : "ar"        "gage"  
  71 : "ar"        "ge"    
  72 : "ar"        "gg"    
  73 : "ar"        "gga"   
  74 : "ar"        "ggag"  
  75 : "ar"        "ggage" 
  76 : "arb"       "a"     
  77 : "arb"       "ag"    
  78 : "arb"       "age"   
  79 : "arb"       "agga"  
  80 : "arb"       "aggage"
  81 : "arb"       "b"     
  82 : "arb"       "bag"   
  83 : "arb"       "bagga" 
  84 : "arb"       "baggage"
  85 : "arb"       "e"     
  86 : "arb"       "g"     
  87 : "arb"       "ga"    
  88 : "arb"       "gage"  
  89 : "arb"       "ge"    
  90 : "arb"       "gga"   
  91 : "arb"       "ggage" 
  92 : "arba"      ""      
  93 : "arba"      "ag"    
  94 : "arba"      "agg"   
  95 : "arba"      "aggag" 
  96 : "arba"      "ba"    
  97 : "arba"      "bagg"  
  98 : "arba"      "baggag"
  99 : "arba"      "g"     
 100 : "arba"      "gag"   
 101 : "arba"      "gg"    
 102 : "arba"      "ggag"  
 103 : "arbar"     "a"     
 104 : "arbar"     "ag"    
 105 : "arbar"     "age"   
 106 : "arbar"     "agga"  
 107 : "arbar"     "aggage"
 108 : "arbar"     "b"     
 109 : "arbar"     "bag"   
 110 : "arbar"     "bagga" 
 111 : "arbar"     "baggage"
 112 : "arbar"     "e"     
 113 : "arbar"     "g"     
 114 : "arbar"     "ga"    
 115 : "arbar"     "gage"  
 116 : "arbar"     "ge"    
 117 : "arbar"     "gga"   
 118 : "arbar"     "ggage" 
 119 : "arbari"    ""      
 120 : "arbari"    "ag"    
 121 : "arbari"    "agg"   
 122 : "arbari"    "aggag" 
 123 : "arbari"    "ba"    
 124 : "arbari"    "bagg"  
 125 : "arbari"    "baggag"
 126 : "arbari"    "g"     
 127 : "arbari"    "gag"   
 128 : "arbari"    "gg"    
 129 : "arbari"    "ggag"  
 130 : "arbaria"   "a"     
 131 : "arbaria"   "ag"    
 132 : "arbaria"   "age"   
 133 : "arbaria"   "agga"  
 134 : "arbaria"   "aggage"
 135 : "arbaria"   "b"     
 136 : "arbaria"   "bag"   
 137 : "arbaria"   "bagga" 
 138 : "arbaria"   "baggage"
 139 : "arbaria"   "e"     
 140 : "arbaria"   "g"     
 141 : "arbaria"   "ga"    
 142 : "arbaria"   "gage"  
 143 : "arbaria"   "ge"    
 144 : "arbaria"   "gga"   
 145 : "arbaria"   "ggage" 
 146 : "arbarian"  ""      
 147 : "arbarian"  "ag"    
 148 : "arbarian"  "agg"   
 149 : "arbarian"  "aggag" 
 150 : "arbarian"  "ba"    
 151 : "arbarian"  "bagg"  
 152 : "arbarian"  "baggag"
 153 : "arbarian"  "g"     
 154 : "arbarian"  "gag"   
 155 : "arbarian"  "gg"    
 156 : "arbarian"  "ggag"  
 157 : "ari"       ""      
 158 : "ari"       "ag"    
 159 : "ari"       "agg"   
 160 : "ari"       "aggag" 
 161 : "ari"       "ba"    
 162 : "ari"       "bagg"  
 163 : "ari"       "baggag"
 164 : "ari"       "g"     
 165 : "ari"       "gag"   
 166 : "ari"       "gg"    
 167 : "ari"       "ggag"  
 168 : "aria"      "a"     
 169 : "aria"      "ag"    
 170 : "aria"      "age"   
 171 : "aria"      "agga"  
 172 : "aria"      "aggage"
 173 : "aria"      "b"     
 174 : "aria"      "bag"   
 175 : "aria"      "bagga" 
 176 : "aria"      "baggage"
 177 : "aria"      "e"     
 178 : "aria"      "g"     
 179 : "aria"      "ga"    
 180 : "aria"      "gage"  
 181 : "aria"      "ge"    
 182 : "aria"      "gga"   
 183 : "aria"      "ggage" 
 184 : "arian"     ""      
 185 : "arian"     "ag"    
 186 : "arian"     "agg"   
 187 : "arian"     "aggag" 
 188 : "arian"     "ba"    
 189 : "arian"     "bagg"  
 190 : "arian"     "baggag"
 191 : "arian"     "g"     
 192 : "arian"     "gag"   
 193 : "arian"     "gg"    
 194 : "arian"     "ggag"  
 195 : "b"         "a"     
 196 : "b"         "ag"    
 197 : "b"         "age"   
 198 : "b"         "agga"  
 199 : "b"         "aggage"
 200 : "b"         "b"     
 201 : "b"         "bag"   
 202 : "b"         "bagga" 
 203 : "b"         "baggage"
 204 : "b"         "e"     
 205 : "b"         "g"     
 206 : "b"         "ga"    
 207 : "b"         "gage"  
 208 : "b"         "ge"    
 209 : "b"         "gga"   
 210 : "b"         "ggage" 
 211 : "ba"        ""      
 212 : "ba"        "ag"    
 213 : "ba"        "agg"   
 214 : "ba"        "aggag" 
 215 : "ba"        "ba"    
 216 : "ba"        "bagg"  
 217 : "ba"        "baggag"
 218 : "ba"        "g"     
 219 : "ba"        "gag"   
 220 : "ba"        "gg"    
 221 : "ba"        "ggag"  
 222 : "bar"       ""      
 223 : "bar"       "a"     
 224 : "bar"       "age"   
 225 : "bar"       "agg"   
 226 : "bar"       "agga"  
 227 : "bar"       "aggag" 
 228 : "bar"       "aggage"
 229 : "bar"       "b"     
 230 : "bar"       "ba"    
 231 : "bar"       "bag"   
 232 : "bar"       "bagg"  
 233 : "bar"       "bagga" 
 234 : "bar"       "baggag"
 235 : "bar"       "baggage"
 236 : "bar"       "e"     
 237 : "bar"       "ga"    
 238 : "bar"       "gag"   
 239 : "bar"       "gage"  
 240 : "bar"       "ge"    
 241 : "bar"       "gg"    
 242 : "bar"       "gga"   
 243 : "bar"       "ggag"  
 244 : "bar"       "ggage" 
 245 : "barb"      "a"     
 246 : "barb"      "ag"    
 247 : "barb"      "age"   
 248 : "barb"      "agga"  
 249 : "barb"      "aggage"
 250 : "barb"      "b"     
 251 : "barb"      "bag"   
 252 : "barb"      "bagga" 
 253 : "barb"      "baggage"
 254 : "barb"      "e"     
 255 : "barb"      "g"     
 256 : "barb"      "ga"    
 257 : "barb"      "gage"  
 258 : "barb"      "ge"    
 259 : "barb"      "gga"   
 260 : "barb"      "ggage" 
 261 : "barba"     ""      
 262 : "barba"     "ag"    
 263 : "barba"     "agg"   
 264 : "barba"     "aggag" 
 265 : "barba"     "ba"    
 266 : "barba"     "bagg"  
 267 : "barba"     "baggag"
 268 : "barba"     "g"     
 269 : "barba"     "gag"   
 270 : "barba"     "gg"    
 271 : "barba"     "ggag"  
 272 : "barbar"    "a"     
 273 : "barbar"    "ag"    
 274 : "barbar"    "age"   
 275 : "barbar"    "agga"  
 276 : "barbar"    "aggage"
 277 : "barbar"    "b"     
 278 : "barbar"    "bag"   
 279 : "barbar"    "bagga" 
 280 : "barbar"    "baggage"
 281 : "barbar"    "e"     
 282 : "barbar"    "g"     
 283 : "barbar"    "ga"    
 284 : "barbar"    "gage"  
 285 : "barbar"    "ge"    
 286 : "barbar"    "gga"   
 287 : "barbar"    "ggage" 
 288 : "barbari"   ""      
 289 : "barbari"   "ag"    
 290 : "barbari"   "agg"   
 291 : "barbari"   "aggag" 
 292 : "barbari"   "ba"    
 293 : "barbari"   "bagg"  
 294 : "barbari"   "baggag"
 295 : "barbari"   "g"     
 296 : "barbari"   "gag"   
 297 : "barbari"   "gg"    
 298 : "barbari"   "ggag"  
 299 : "barbaria"  "a"     
 300 : "barbaria"  "ag"    
 301 : "barbaria"  "age"   
 302 : "barbaria"  "agga"  
 303 : "barbaria"  "aggage"
 304 : "barbaria"  "b"     
 305 : "barbaria"  "bag"   
 306 : "barbaria"  "bagga" 
 307 : "barbaria"  "baggage"
 308 : "barbaria"  "e"     
 309 : "barbaria"  "g"     
 310 : "barbaria"  "ga"    
 311 : "barbaria"  "gage"  
 312 : "barbaria"  "ge"    
 313 : "barbaria"  "gga"   
 314 : "barbaria"  "ggage" 
 315 : "barbarian" ""      
 316 : "barbarian" "ag"    
 317 : "barbarian" "agg"   
 318 : "barbarian" "aggag" 
 319 : "barbarian" "ba"    
 320 : "barbarian" "bagg"  
 321 : "barbarian" "baggag"
 322 : "barbarian" "g"     
 323 : "barbarian" "gag"   
 324 : "barbarian" "gg"    
 325 : "barbarian" "ggag"  
 326 : "bari"      ""      
 327 : "bari"      "ag"    
 328 : "bari"      "agg"   
 329 : "bari"      "aggag" 
 330 : "bari"      "ba"    
 331 : "bari"      "bagg"  
 332 : "bari"      "baggag"
 333 : "bari"      "g"     
 334 : "bari"      "gag"   
 335 : "bari"      "gg"    
 336 : "bari"      "ggag"  
 337 : "baria"     "a"     
 338 : "baria"     "ag"    
 339 : "baria"     "age"   
 340 : "baria"     "agga"  
 341 : "baria"     "aggage"
 342 : "baria"     "b"     
 343 : "baria"     "bag"   
 344 : "baria"     "bagga" 
 345 : "baria"     "baggage"
 346 : "baria"     "e"     
 347 : "baria"     "g"     
 348 : "baria"     "ga"    
 349 : "baria"     "gage"  
 350 : "baria"     "ge"    
 351 : "baria"     "gga"   
 352 : "baria"     "ggage" 
 353 : "barian"    ""      
 354 : "barian"    "ag"    
 355 : "barian"    "agg"   
 356 : "barian"    "aggag" 
 357 : "barian"    "ba"    
 358 : "barian"    "bagg"  
 359 : "barian"    "baggag"
 360 : "barian"    "g"     
 361 : "barian"    "gag"   
 362 : "barian"    "gg"    
 363 : "barian"    "ggag"  
 364 : "i"         ""      
 365 : "i"         "ag"    
 366 : "i"         "agg"   
 367 : "i"         "aggag" 
 368 : "i"         "ba"    
 369 : "i"         "bagg"  
 370 : "i"         "baggag"
 371 : "i"         "g"     
 372 : "i"         "gag"   
 373 : "i"         "gg"    
 374 : "i"         "ggag"  
 375 : "ia"        "a"     
 376 : "ia"        "ag"    
 377 : "ia"        "age"   
 378 : "ia"        "agga"  
 379 : "ia"        "aggage"
 380 : "ia"        "b"     
 381 : "ia"        "bag"   
 382 : "ia"        "bagga" 
 383 : "ia"        "baggage"
 384 : "ia"        "e"     
 385 : "ia"        "g"     
 386 : "ia"        "ga"    
 387 : "ia"        "gage"  
 388 : "ia"        "ge"    
 389 : "ia"        "gga"   
 390 : "ia"        "ggage" 
 391 : "ian"       ""      
 392 : "ian"       "ag"    
 393 : "ian"       "agg"   
 394 : "ian"       "aggag" 
 395 : "ian"       "ba"    
 396 : "ian"       "bagg"  
 397 : "ian"       "baggag"
 398 : "ian"       "g"     
 399 : "ian"       "gag"   
 400 : "ian"       "gg"    
 401 : "ian"       "ggag"  
 402 : "n"         ""      
 403 : "n"         "ag"    
 404 : "n"         "agg"   
 405 : "n"         "aggag" 
 406 : "n"         "ba"    
 407 : "n"         "bagg"  
 408 : "n"         "baggag"
 409 : "n"         "g"     
 410 : "n"         "gag"   
 411 : "n"         "gg"    
 412 : "n"         "ggag"  
 413 : "r"         ""      
 414 : "r"         "a"     
 415 : "r"         "age"   
 416 : "r"         "agg"   
 417 : "r"         "agga"  
 418 : "r"         "aggag" 
 419 : "r"         "aggage"
 420 : "r"         "b"     
 421 : "r"         "ba"    
 422 : "r"         "bag"   
 423 : "r"         "bagg"  
 424 : "r"         "bagga" 
 425 : "r"         "baggag"
 426 : "r"         "baggage"
 427 : "r"         "e"     
 428 : "r"         "ga"    
 429 : "r"         "gag"   
 430 : "r"         "gage"  
 431 : "r"         "ge"    
 432 : "r"         "gg"    
 433 : "r"         "gga"   
 434 : "r"         "ggag"  
 435 : "r"         "ggage" 
 436 : "rb"        "a"     
 437 : "rb"        "ag"    
 438 : "rb"        "age"   
 439 : "rb"        "agga"  
 440 : "rb"        "aggage"
 441 : "rb"        "b"     
 442 : "rb"        "bag"   
 443 : "rb"        "bagga" 
 444 : "rb"        "baggage"
 445 : "rb"        "e"     
 446 : "rb"        "g"     
 447 : "rb"        "ga"    
 448 : "rb"        "gage"  
 449 : "rb"        "ge"    
 450 : "rb"        "gga"   
 451 : "rb"        "ggage" 
 452 : "rba"       ""      
 453 : "rba"       "ag"    
 454 : "rba"       "agg"   
 455 : "rba"       "aggag" 
 456 : "rba"       "ba"    
 457 : "rba"       "bagg"  
 458 : "rba"       "baggag"
 459 : "rba"       "g"     
 460 : "rba"       "gag"   
 461 : "rba"       "gg"    
 462 : "rba"       "ggag"  
 463 : "rbar"      "a"     
 464 : "rbar"      "ag"    
 465 : "rbar"      "age"   
 466 : "rbar"      "agga"  
 467 : "rbar"      "aggage"
 468 : "rbar"      "b"     
 469 : "rbar"      "bag"   
 470 : "rbar"      "bagga" 
 471 : "rbar"      "baggage"
 472 : "rbar"      "e"     
 473 : "rbar"      "g"     
 474 : "rbar"      "ga"    
 475 : "rbar"      "gage"  
 476 : "rbar"      "ge"    
 477 : "rbar"      "gga"   
 478 : "rbar"      "ggage" 
 479 : "rbari"     ""      
 480 : "rbari"     "ag"    
 481 : "rbari"     "agg"   
 482 : "rbari"     "aggag" 
 483 : "rbari"     "ba"    
 484 : "rbari"     "bagg"  
 485 : "rbari"     "baggag"
 486 : "rbari"     "g"     
 487 : "rbari"     "gag"   
 488 : "rbari"     "gg"    
 489 : "rbari"     "ggag"  
 490 : "rbaria"    "a"     
 491 : "rbaria"    "ag"    
 492 : "rbaria"    "age"   
 493 : "rbaria"    "agga"  
 494 : "rbaria"    "aggage"
 495 : "rbaria"    "b"     
 496 : "rbaria"    "bag"   
 497 : "rbaria"    "bagga" 
 498 : "rbaria"    "baggage"
 499 : "rbaria"    "e"     
 500 : "rbaria"    "g"     
 501 : "rbaria"    "ga"    
 502 : "rbaria"    "gage"  
 503 : "rbaria"    "ge"    
 504 : "rbaria"    "gga"   
 505 : "rbaria"    "ggage" 
 506 : "rbarian"   ""      
 507 : "rbarian"   "ag"    
 508 : "rbarian"   "agg"   
 509 : "rbarian"   "aggag" 
 510 : "rbarian"   "ba"    
 511 : "rbarian"   "bagg"  
 512 : "rbarian"   "baggag"
 513 : "rbarian"   "g"     
 514 : "rbarian"   "gag"   
 515 : "rbarian"   "gg"    
 516 : "rbarian"   "ggag"  
 517 : "ri"        ""      
 518 : "ri"        "ag"    
 519 : "ri"        "agg"   
 520 : "ri"        "aggag" 
 521 : "ri"        "ba"    
 522 : "ri"        "bagg"  
 523 : "ri"        "baggag"
 524 : "ri"        "g"     
 525 : "ri"        "gag"   
 526 : "ri"        "gg"    
 527 : "ri"        "ggag"  
 528 : "ria"       "a"     
 529 : "ria"       "ag"    
 530 : "ria"       "age"   
 531 : "ria"       "agga"  
 532 : "ria"       "aggage"
 533 : "ria"       "b"     
 534 : "ria"       "bag"   
 535 : "ria"       "bagga" 
 536 : "ria"       "baggage"
 537 : "ria"       "e"     
 538 : "ria"       "g"     
 539 : "ria"       "ga"    
 540 : "ria"       "gage"  
 541 : "ria"       "ge"    
 542 : "ria"       "gga"   
 543 : "ria"       "ggage" 
 544 : "rian"      ""      
 545 : "rian"      "ag"    
 546 : "rian"      "agg"   
 547 : "rian"      "aggag" 
 548 : "rian"      "ba"    
 549 : "rian"      "bagg"  
 550 : "rian"      "baggag"
 551 : "rian"      "g"     
 552 : "rian"      "gag"   
 553 : "rian"      "gg"    
 554 : "rian"      "ggag"
```

which is not that simple. I don't think there is a direct general and simple way to compute the kth winning position.